# what is the difference between public static synchronized and public static?

Tags: java

as i said ,
what is the difference between
`public static synchronized ..` and 
 `public static`  ?
any example ?

Comment: one's synchronized and the other isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One point you have to be careful about (several programmers generally fall in that trap) is that there is no link between synchronized static methods and non synchronized static methods, ie:

```
class A {
    public static synchronized f() {...} //class level lock
    public static g() {...} //object level lock
}
public class TestA{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
       //Thread 1:
       a.f();
       //Thread 2:
       a.g();
    }
}
```

f() and g() are not synchronized with each other and thus can execute totally concurrently.

Comment: which method is faster performance wise ?

also im not getting , what is the actual use of this method , lets say for , if , both have the same code , like doing something with an object
and they are being called like few times in some random class

Comment: When you put any lock class level or object level, there will be degrade in performance. Thats why we go for immutable classes which are surely thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

synchronized keyword ensures that a method can be invoked by only one thread at a time. If you don't put synchronized, it is not essentially Thread-safe.

Comment: being synchronized is related to thread safety but it doesn't guarantee thread safety, nor does the lack of synchronization mean a method is not thread safe.

Comment: I know. But that much info is enough at this stage :)

Answer (score 1):

- static synchronized  -  on a method
  obtain a lock on the Class
- static

  static means one per class, not one for each object no matter how
     many instance of a class might exist.
     This means that you can use them
     without creating an instance of a
     class.Static methods are implicitly
     final, because overriding is done
     based on the type of the object, and
     static methods are attached to a
     class, not an object. A static method
     in a superclass can be shadowed by
     another static method in a subclass,
     as long as the original method was
     not declared final. However, you
     can't override a static method with a
     nonstatic method. In other words, you
     can't change a static method into an
     instance method in a subclass.

Comment: what do u mean when u say lock on a class ?